# How do I make variable names that replace a c function an error?

Tags: c++, c, linker, clang

My code mysteriously stop working. I figured out I accidentally wrote `int listen;` in my `main.cpp` and used listen in my `network.cpp` which seems to be trying to call the int as a function instead of the C function. Changing the name of the variable (or making it static) fixed the problem.

Is there any warnings I can turn on so I don't get caught by something like this again? The closest I found was something that suggest I make variables static if they don't need to be extern

Heres code

```
//a.cpp
#include<cstdio>
int main() { puts("Hello"); }
```

---

```
//b.cpp
int puts;
```

Comment: You should probably have your own `namespace` to avoid such collisions.

Comment: "stop working" is not a description of the problem. And you need to show a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: apart from using a namespace, people also often add a "g_" before a global variable

Comment: @tb044491 More often yet, people ban the use of global variables entirely.

Comment: Which compiler are you asking about?

Comment: @Jarod42: That looks like a solution I can use. I'm using `-Werror=missing-variable-declarations` as well. Is there a way you can post your answer so I can mark it correct? I tried editing but that didn't seem to open it up again

Comment: @bolov and the mods. Why delete my comment and not bolov when he clearly didn't read the question?

Comment: @EricStotch I have read the question. And it's unclear and lacks important details. As I've said "My code stop working" is not a description of the problem. "I wrote `int listen;` in my main.cpp and used `listen` in my network.cpp" is a poor description of a code. We don't know what that means. We can only speculate. You shouldn't describing your code, instead you should create a [MRE], that way we can see exactly what you did and we don't have to assume and fill the unknowns. ....

Comment: ... "seems to be trying to call the int as a function instead of the C function" again is a poor, confusing description of the error. Instead what you should do is post the exact error message (copy-paste) the compiler is giving. In conclusion: don't describe your code, instead post a [MRE] and don't describe your error, instead post the compiler error exactly.

Comment: @bolov fyi it has to do with linking, not code. Anyone who knows C would understand this. declaring the variable listen (`int listen`) is literally the bug. The first comment clearly understood the problem. I have no time to teach you C and linking so you can understand the problem others can understand

Comment: @EricStotch The first commenter assumed you wrote `int listen` at global scope. It happened to be a lucky assumption in this case, but in general making assumptions here is a bad think. Many many times on this site I've seen people making assumptions about unclear and underspecified questions, taking the time to write answers based on those assumptions only for the answers (and their time) to be wasted because their assumptions were wrong.

Comment: and I don't understand your aggressiveness. All I am saying is to make your question clear, unambiguous and complete. This is to help you in getting answers here.

Comment: @bolov I understand you have no idea how the linker works. I also understand you decided for other people question is unclear including people who actually have a clue how a linker works. You quite literally asked me what the error message is and act like you're still in the right

Comment: @Lundin I'm curious, why did you close my question?

Comment: @EricStotch Because it's not clear what problem you have and what warnings you are getting. Without the code in the form of a [mcve], we can only guess what you are trying to say. Also please quote the compiler warnings.

Comment: @EricStotch No, I truly don't understand what you mean with "which seems to be trying to call the int as a function instead of the C function". What function? What call? **Post code**. We cannot suggest a cure if we don't know the cause.

Comment: @bolov: you too. Good luck using the code instead of the actual description of the problem. The produced executable segfaults when you compile `clang++ a.cpp b.cpp` but doesn't if you only compile `clang++ a.cpp`.

Comment: Banning global variables is completely ridiculous. Huge codebases use global stuff for various important things that are being used all the time, example: game engines, UE4 etc. I was under the impression for at least a year that globals are to be avoided so much that I was almost too afraid to even think about using them. I was dead wrong. If you're not doing microcontrollers, low-power devices you can use them for whatever reason you like and don't worry about it AT ALL, unless there's a reason to (in which case, you'll be advanced enough in your coding career that you will know what to do).

Comment: @Nikos do you happen to know what compile options people use when working with unreal? The traditional `-Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra` didn't catch my error :( (missing-variable-declarations did)

Comment: @EricStotch Use Visual Studio 2017/2019 for UE4. You don't need to specify compile options yourself, just RMB on .uproject file -> Generate Visual Studio files (it's called something like that); Everything will be generated on the fly. Then open the generated .sln solution inside the folder and build and launch it. Google ue4 compiling game projects for more info about more advanced things you can do if you want more; but you likely won't need to. And this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Nikos: "*I was dead wrong.*" Why? Because UE4 uses them? Does that somehow make all of the very real problems that come from global variables disappear? Does it make modifiable global state easier to reason about? Does it make code based on global state not extremely difficult to test effectively? The fact that someone manages to avoid blowing their foot off should not be taken as a reason to aim a gun at your own foot. Bad programming practices can be bad even if someone manages to make something big and complicated successfully with them.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an ODR violation. You have two different definitions of `puts` in two different TUs. The standard (N4713 - C++17 draft) says

> **§6.2 One-definition rule [basic.def.odr]**
>
> 10. Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used in that program
>       outside of a discarded statement (9.4.1); no diagnostic required.

This is of course for C++. C has similar rules.

Because of the "no diagnostic required" the compiler chain is not required to issue errors or warnings for your code.

As far as I know there are no flags on popular compilers to issue error/warnings for ODR violations. This is because of how compilers optimize their parsing. See [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45922493/2805305) for more info on that.

There are some good practices that you can follow to minimize this kind of mistake:

- In C++ don't declare symbols at global space. Use namespaces.
- In C you can prefix global variables with `g_`. If you write a library you also add a library prefix to everything global.
- (as you've suggested) make symbols that are used only in their TU have internal linkage (declare them `static` or in an unnamed namespace).
- use more meaningful, relevant names. E.g. instead of `listen` you can name it `server_is_listening` (or something like that that makes sense for its use).

Answer (score 0):

`-Werror=missing-variable-declarations` may help. It forces you to use static which avoids this problem or declare the variable elsewhere (ie a header). Including that header in any file that includes the C function will cause an error causing another chance to catch the error